# Concept or trait for functor with specific arguments?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, type-traits, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to create a `concept` that can be used to safe check that a functor has a certain criteria.
This is my code right now:

```
template<typename T>
void fetch(T&& f)
{
  fetch_helper(&f, &std::unwrap_ref_decay_t<T>::operator());
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void fetch_helper(T* obj, void (T::*f)(Args...) const)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

I use `fetch` to take a functor object and then use `fetch_helper` to operate on it. However I want to implement pref. a `concept` or `type trait` that would check that the arguments types are unique (which I already have an implemented concept for `IsUnique<T...>`). So that the program doesnt compile if the functor doesnt follow the criteria.

```
// compiles
fetch([](int h){

});

// doesnt compile
fetch([](int h, int j){

});
```

How can I apply my constrait `IsUnique` to the args of the functor object in fetch? I tried adding the `requires` concept to my helper function but that still allows fetch to be called with bad arguments. I somehow has to apply the constraint of the arguments in fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
    requires IsUnique<Args...>
void fetch_helper(T* obj, void (T::*f)(Args...) const) 
{
  // do stuff
}

template<typename T>
    requires requires (T&& f) {fetch_helper(&f, &std::unwrap_ref_decay_t<T>::operator());}
void fetch(T&& f)
{
  fetch_helper(&f, &std::unwrap_ref_decay_t<T>::operator());
}
```

Comment: that doesnt compile for me, my unique constrait is not being applied

Comment: Nevermind must have done something else wrong, it works

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want something like this:

```cpp
// TypeTraits if IsUnique is a typical trait inheriting from std::true_type or std::false_type
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<IsUnique<Args...>::value> fetch_helper(T* obj, void (T::*f)(Args...) const)
{
  // do stuff
}

// Concept
template<typename T, typename... Args> requires (IsUnique<Args...>)
void fetch_helper(T* obj, void (T::*f)(Args...) const)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

If you want to check already in `fetch` you can add a constraint whether `fetch_helper` is callable with the appropriate arguments (basically repeating the code inside).